# Как JSON строку превратить в массив с элементами?

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Вот строка:

```
let str = '[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]';
```

Подскажите решение пожалуйста(

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let str = '[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]';
let arr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: О, спасибо! (4 символа)

Comment: No problemo 0:-)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, JSON.parse(str)